# r : Ignore NA values with pmax function

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new column with the max values of 3 columns.

data exemple :

```
date          skyc1 skyc2 skyc3 
1995-01-01    0     1     3
1995-01-02    1     null  null
1995-01-03    1     3     null
```

I would like to get :

```
date          skyc1 skyc2 skyc3 max
1995-01-01    0     1     3     3
1995-01-02    1     null  null  1
1995-01-03    1     3     null  3
```

I tried using :

```
df$max <- pmax(df$skyc1,df$skyc2,df$skyc3)
```

But I get this :

```
date          skyc1 skyc2 skyc3 max
1995-01-01    0     1     3     3
1995-01-02    1     null  null  null
1995-01-03    1     3     null  null
```

Is it possible to consider null as 0 ? I have thought about replacing null to 0 but I have values that are actually 0 in my dataset...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `na.rm` in `pmax` and as the values are `null`, we need to `replace` those `null` to `NA` before doing that and as "null" is a character string, the columns would be `character` or `factor`.  So, we need to also change the `type` with `type.convert` before the `pmax` step

```
df[-1] <- replace(df[-1], df[-1] == "null", NA)
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
df$max <- pmax(df$skyc1, df$skyc2, df$skyc3, na.rm = TRUE)
df$max
#[1] 3 1 3
```

If there are many columns of 'skyc',then it can be automated as well

```
nm1 <- grep('^skyc\\d+$', names(df), value = TRUE)
df$max <- do.call(pmax, c(df[nm1], na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df <-structure(list(date = c("1995-01-01", "1995-01-02", "1995-01-03"
), skyc1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), skyc2 = c("1", "null", "3"), skyc3 = c("3", 
"null", "null")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'm quite new with R. I tried running your codes as this : CYKGfull[-1] <- replace(CYKGfull[-1] CYKGfull[-1] == "null", NA) (df name is CYKGfull), but I get an error message :
Error: unexpected symbol in "CYKGfull[-1] <- replace(CYKGfull[-1] CYKGfull"

Comment: @Will_8011 There was a typo in my earlier code as the `,` should be there between `CYKGfull[-1] CYKGfull"` i.e. `CYKGfull[-1], CYKGfull"` can you try the updated code

Comment: @Will_8011 The `CYKGfull == "null"` should be `CYKGfull[-1]` == "null"` as we want to do this on equal dimensions.  Based on the example, only the skyc columns have 'null', so the `-1` is to consider removing the first column from the comparison

Comment: ok! So i used : CYKGfull[-1] <- replace(CYKGfull[-1], CYKGfull[-1] == "null", NA)  still gives me this error message : Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: So I think I solved the issue : first I used    CYKGfull <- type.convert(CYKGfull, as.is = TRUE) then ran     CYKGfull[CYKGfull == "null"] <- NA, and then the pmax function, looks like everything is good now. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Will_8011 sorry, was away